# VMWare SDK Java samples cannot connect to vCenter

Tags: java, web-services, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I've a Windows 2008 virtual machine whose IP address is 192.168.3.150, on which I have installed the **vCenter Server**. As I am not expert on vSphere, I have just done a **Simple Install**. Then on my laptop whose IP is 192.168.2.36, I can open the **Web Client** in my browser.

Both machines can ping each other, so I think the network connection is OK.

However when I tried to run the Java samples of SDK package, they can't connect to the vCenter.

`run.bat com.vmware.general.SimpleClient --url https://192.168.3.150/sdk --username Administrator@vsphere.local --password blablabla --ignorecert ignorecert`

I got an error message:

`WARNING: Java is now set to trust all SSL certificates.
-- VMware samples in Java --
The server at https://192.168.3.150:7444/ims/STSService did not respond as expec
ted. Is this a valid URL?Note: SSO connections only work on vCenter SSO enabled
products.
Use the --basic-connection switch if you know this is an ESX host.
See the connection.properties file for more instructions.
No valid connection available. Exiting now.
Done.`

I have tried to run the samples in the virtual machine, same problem.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Make sure the time is correct on your vcenter/sso server and that all the services are started

Comment: Also administrator@vsphere.local is generally all lowercase

Comment: @vbranden All the services are running. I have tried **a**dministrator@vsphere.local, but no, it doesn't work, the account **A**dministrator was created during vCenter installation. I think it is the the Windows default administrator account. I can login the Web Client by using the account **A**dministrator@vsphere.local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved the program by following the tutorial [Getting Started With the vSphere Management SDK](http://blogs.vmware.com/developer/2014/07/getting-started-vsphere-management-sdk.html). I can finally connect to my vCenter by using its code. It turns out to be a certificate verification issue. I don't know why the option `--ignorecert` of the SDK samples doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works perfectly fine for VI java SDK. Pass 'true' in new ServiceInstance as last parameter to ignoreCert.

```
        URL serviceUrl = new URL("https://192.168.3.150/sdk");
        return new ServiceInstance(serviceUrl, "Administrator@vsphere.local","blablabla", true);
```